# Include file in play framework

Tags: file, scala, jar, playframework

How can i include txt files and access to them within play framework? I need to load some text from .txt files depending on user request. I'm used to access files from inside jars and thinking in deploying the web as a runnable jar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same thing in Play. It doesn't matter whether your application is packaged as a jar file or not.

The resource file just needs to be on the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: But im not using an IDE, last time i used the command "play dist". Are files included in that way?. Also, before posting i put some files there but could not find them under the "target" folder

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're using an IDE or not - Play is specifically designed to be perfectly usable without an IDE. Yes, `play dist` should include them. Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Right now 2.2.1 . I made some tests inside app and folders inside app but i dont see them included nor compiled. Maybe the name is changed?, also, i'm using debian.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. `app` can be used for compiled assets like LESS stylesheets, but not for simple files. Try putting it in `conf` instead.